# ¿ Como obtener atributos y capturarlos en otra pagina con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, undefined

En mi index, cargo con otros scripts las peliculas y series de forma dinamica, asignando todos los atributos a los link e imagenes, ellos me deberian llevar a una pagina siguiente que la relleno con el script que coloque debajo al momento de seleccionar un link, del link que seleccion necestio capturar el atributo title para utilizar al momento de rellenar la pagina que creo de forma dinamica.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>FunnyNet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/preloader.css">

</head>
<body class="hidden">

<!--Preloader-->
<div class="centrado" id="onload">
    <div class="lds-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>
<!--Fin Preloader-->
<header>

    <nav id="nav" class="nav1">
        <div class="contenedor-nav">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo3.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="enlaces" id="enlaces">
                <a href="#" id="enlace-inicio" class="btn-header">Inicio</a>
                <a href="#" id="enlace-peli" class="btn-header">Peliculas</a>
                <a href="#" id="enlace-stv" class="btn-header">Series y TV</a>
                <a href="#" id="enlace-docu" class="btn-header">Documentales</a>
                <a href="#" id="enlace-depor" class="btn-header">Deportes</a>
                <a href="#" id="enlace-mus" class="btn-header">Musicales</a>
            </div>
            <div class="icono" id="open">
                <span>&#9776;</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="textos">
        <h1>Bienvenido a FunnyNet</h1>
        <h2>¡Disfruta de un viaje plancetero viendo lo que mas te gusta!</h2>
    </div>
</header>
<main>

    <section class="contenedor">
            <h3>Peliculas Estreno</h3>
            <div class="peliculas" id="cont-video" onclick="captura_link()">

            </div>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section class="contenedor">
            <h3>Series Estreno</h3>
            <div class="series" id="cont-video" onclick="captura_link()">


            </div>

    </section>

</main>
<footer id="contacto">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="marca-logo">
            <img src="img/logo3.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <p>Copyright © 2019 FunnyNet. Todos los Derechos Reservados.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/filtro.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/cargarvideo.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(".peliculas").load("leer_pelicula.php");
        $(".series").load("leer_serie.php");

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Esta seria la otra pagina donde cargarian los videos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reproducir.css">
    <title>¡A Disfrutar!</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-video">
        <div class="panel-video" id="reproduciendo">

        </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/cargarvideo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

en mi JS tengo una funcion que me captura el valor del atributo titulo del link al cual estoy haciendo clik seria algo asi.

```
 function captura_link(){

        const dir_peli = $('a').attr("title");
        console.log(dir_peli);
    }

$(window).ready(function(){
const cont_video = document.getElementById("reproduciendo");

const video = document.createElement("video");

video.setAttribute("class", "multimedia");
video.setAttribute("id", "repro-video");
video.setAttribute("controls", "");
video.setAttribute("disablePictureInPicture", "");
video.setAttribute("autoplay", "enable");
video.setAttribute("controlslist","nodownload");
video.setAttribute("src","peliculas/7_almas/SieteAlmas.mp4");
video.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");

cont_video.appendChild(video);

});
```

Me da undefined como puedo arreglar para capturar el valor y evitar el error. Gracias

Comment: Depende de en que momento estés cargando ese script? al principio o al final? como cargas los `a`, deberías poner los ejemplos

Comment: Coloca por favor en que parte ejecutas tu script, además unos datos de **muestra** para poder replicar tu escenario

Comment: esta colocado al final

Comment: </footer>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/filtro.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/cargarvideo.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        
        $(".peliculas").load("leer_pelicula.php");
        $(".series").load("leer_serie.php");
    
    </script>

    
</body>
</html>

Comment: yo uso otros script para cargar los link e imagenes usando manejo de archivos

Comment: Hola @RomuloLoyo, en el código html no veo el elemento con `id="reproduciendo"`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reproducir.css">
    <title>¡A Disfrutar!</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-video">
        <div class="panel-video" id="reproduciendo">
        
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/cargarvideo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ya actualice arriba

Comment: En todo el código que has puesto no veo ninguna etiqueta `<a>` con un atributo `title`.

Comment: es que los cargo de forma dinámica con un js, en si la cuestión no es eso, imaginate que tengas una etiqueta <a> con el atributo title dentro de los div de peliculas y series, quiero capturar ese atributo para usarlo en la otra pagina que coloque debajo del index.

Comment: Si la función `captura_link()` la cargas en el mismo HTML donde se encuentran esos links que quieres capturar, el método debería funcionarte.

Comment: como dije antes los cargo dinamicamente con un script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer click sobre el elemento `<a>` lo que haces es recargar o redireccionar la pagina tiene dos opciones , enviar por URL el titulo del vídeo o guardar el titulo en `localStorage` cuando se encuentre en la otra pagina *( del mismo dominio )* podrá acceder al titulo guardado y concatenar en el `src` del vídeo.

Aquie agrego un ejemplo. *(uso `<form>` para simular la redireccion )* , puedes probar el codigo en [codepen click aquí](https://codepen.io/damesad/pen/OKBNvJ?editors=1111).

```js
function ver(element){
  const titulo = element.getAttribute('title')
  console.log(titulo)
  localStorage.setItem('video_title',titulo)

}

function reproducir(){
  const cont_video = document.getElementById("reproduciendo");
  const video_titulo = localStorage.getItem('video_title');
  if(video_titulo !== null && video_titulo !== '' ){
    console.log(video_titulo)
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    video.setAttribute("class", "multimedia");
    video.setAttribute("id", "repro-video");
    video.setAttribute("controls", "");
    video.setAttribute("disablePictureInPicture", "");
    video.setAttribute("autoplay", "enable");
    video.setAttribute("controlslist","nodownload");
  video.setAttribute("src","peliculas/7_almas/"+video_titulo+".mp4");
    video.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
    cont_video.appendChild(video);
  }
}

function showTutitulo(){
  const video_titulo = localStorage.getItem('video_title');
  if(video_titulo !== null && video_titulo !== '' ){
    document.getElementById('btn').innerText = "Reproducir "+video_titulo
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  showTutitulo()
}
```

```html
<div id="reproduciendo">
<button onclick="reproducir()" id="btn">Reproducir</button>
<form action="">
<button type="submit" title="SieteAlmas.mp4" onclick="ver(this)">Ver SieteAlmas</button>
<button type="submit" title="OchoAlmas.mp4" onclick="ver(this)">Ver OchoAlmas</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias Diego, ya lo estoy adaptando mi código y funciona perfecto! soy nuevo con JS me ha costado un poco pero hay vamos agradecido!